# Script using "<()" syntax works in bash but causes syntax error in os.system()

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x

I am attempting to run a `bash` command in my python script, but it is failing with:

`sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token`('`

The script is pretty simple...

```
import os

os.system('bash <(curl -f -L -sS https://ngxpagespeed.com/install) --assume-yes --nginx-version latest -a "--prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=www-data --group=www-data --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-ipv6 --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module"')
```

But I cannot see where I am going wrong with it.

The exact command run in shell works fine:

```
bash <(curl -f -L -sS https://ngxpagespeed.com/install) --assume-yes \
  --nginx-version latest -a "--prefix=/etc/nginx \
  --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules \
  --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
  --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
  --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock \
  --http-client-body-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/client_temp \
  --http-proxy-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/proxy_temp \
  --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp \
  --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp \
  --http-scgi-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=www-data \
  --group=www-data --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-ipv6 \
  --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module \
  --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module \
  --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module \
  --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module \
  --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module \
  --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module \
  --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail \
  --with-mail_ssl_module --with-http_xslt_module \
  --with-http_image_filter_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module"
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: The error is from bash. Does your command line even run from shell?

Comment: It does... just fine

Comment: the exact command i run in shell is..... too long to post in a comment apparently lol

Comment: I see you're using a bash-ism `<(...)`, but the error report says `sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token '('`. Note that it says `sh`, not `bash`. I'd try to use `/bin/bash` in the `os.system` invocation; maybe you get `sh` substituted for `bash` in the env where you run the Python code.

Comment: i will certainly try that :)  tho it's odd that it would do that...

Comment: same error.  literally `sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token('`

Comment: When I break it up into seperate statements it works fine... maybe it's the `bash` piping to `curl`?

Comment: I'd try to make the simplest thing work first, e.g. `bash <(echo "echo 'It worked'")`. I'd also look at `subprocess` module that _might_ help sidestep the wrong shell issue by not invoking the user's shell at all.

Comment: @9000, `subprocess` doesn't help in and of itself -- using it with `shell=True` still uses `/bin/sh` -- but with `shell=False`, it gives the user full control of which, if any, shell is used.

Comment: @9000, ...note that `system()` doesn't use "the user's" shell -- it's hardcoded to `/bin/sh` (as well it should be -- that way it's guaranteed to be POSIX-compliant, rather than whatever random shell someone decides they want to use interactively; otherwise, someone using `fish` or `planck` would break a whole lot of programs).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Indeed! `os.system` does _not_ allow to run without a shell; `shell=False`, `subprocess` just calls `execvp` without invoking a shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: «it's hardcoded to `/bin/sh`» must explain it all then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/bin/sh`, as used by `system()`, does not support `<()`. Use `bash` instead, not just to invoke the downloaded script, but also to interpret the command that runs the download.

```
script = '''bash <(curl -f -L -sS https://ngxpagespeed.com/install) --assume-yes --nginx-version latest -a "--prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=www-data --group=www-data --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-ipv6 --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module'''
subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', script])
```

Alternately, the outer script can be rewritten easily enough to be POSIX-compliant, passing the code to run to the interpreter on stdin rather than via a filename or process substitution:

```
os.system('curl -f -L -sS https://ngxpagespeed.com/install | bash -s --assume-yes  --nginx-version latest -a "--prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=www-data --group=www-data --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-ipv6 --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module')
```

<sub>By the way -- downloading unsigned code over the Internet and directly invoking it in this manner is a really, *really* bad idea, and I'm not by any means intending to condone it by answering this question.</sub>

Comment: Appreciate the help... i did not know that about `system`.  Seems I have to rethink this further, as the script will not run `sudo make install` now once the rest of it is finished LOL  Thanks Google :D

Answer (score 0):

Switching it to this has "fixed" the issue

```
os.system('wget -O /tmp/install https://ngxpagespeed.com/install')
os.system('bash /tmp/install --assume-yes --nginx-version latest -a "--prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/media/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=www-data --group=www-data --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-ipv6 --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module"')
```

Comment: BTW, if you *are* going to use a temporary file, use the `tempfile.NamedTempFile` module, or otherwise create a random, unique name -- it's not remotely unheard for an attacker to precreate symlinks in `/tmp` to cause other processes to overwrite privileged files that that attacker themselves doesn't have sufficient permissions to write.